# Convert object to string and fill NA in case value is not present javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, lodash

I am trying to convert a string into an object and fill NA in case the value for that key is not present.

I have a string like this.

```
 let stroy =  {"Name":"","Id":"abc",  "test": "" "}
```

with this

```
JSON.Parse(stroy)
```

I am able to convert , but How to fill NA in case no value is present.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: you can traverse the object and add n/a if there is no data for a particular key !

Comment: `JSON.parse` (note the lower case `P`) will not convert what you've shown to an object. What you've shown already **is** an object, that's an object literal, not a string. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop the object after parsing.
While looping just check whether data found in that key or not

```js
let stroy =  `{"Name":"","Id":"abc",  "test": ""}`
stroy = JSON.parse(stroy)
for (var key in stroy) {
  if(!stroy[key]) {
    stroy[key] = 'NA'
  }
}
console.log(stroy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a list of key / values pairs. If the value is empty we'll replace it with a default value, in this case 'NA'.

We're use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert back to an object.

```js
let stroy = {"Name":"", "Id":"abc", "test": ""};
const defaultValue = 'NA';

let result = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(stroy).map(key => {
    return [key, stroy[key] || defaultValue ];
}));

console.log('Result:', result);
```